# Creating a receipt with name of item, quantity, and total price

Tags: c++

How can I create a receipt that will print all of the name of the item chosen, quantity, and its total price after the user inputs `No` or stops buying?

I used `switch` so it's hard for me to find any references about receipt.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 char acoustic, electric, drums, piano, music, equip, Yes, No, y, name;

int pay, Qty;
std::string again;

int main()
{

{
cout << "Welcome to the Music Shop" << endl <<endl;
cout << "                                                                         ===========================                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |       Categories        |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [a] Acoustic Guitar    |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [b] Electric Guitar    |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [c] Drums              |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [d] Piano              |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         |  [e] Music Equipments   |                            "<<endl;
cout << "                                                                         ===========================                            "<<endl;


do {    
cout << "                                                                     Choose from the available categories:";
cin >> music;
cout << ""<<endl;

switch (music)
{
    case 'a':

    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                Acoustic Guitars             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [1] Fender Acoustic Guitar      P6,900.00   |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [2] Hartwood Acoustic Guitar    P6,300.00   |" << endl;
    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
    cin>>acoustic;

    if (acoustic == '1'){
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>Qty;
        cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Fender Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;

    }
    else if (acoustic == '2'){
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>Qty;
        cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Hartwood Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
    } 

    break;

    case 'b':

    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                Electric Guitars             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [1] Gibson Electric Guitar      P8,500.00   |" << endl;
    cout<< "                                                             | [2] Ibanez Electric Guitar      P25,000.00  |" << endl;
    cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Electric Guitars:";
    cin>>electric;

        if (electric=='1'){           
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>Qty;
        cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Gibson Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again; 
    }
        else if (electric=='2'){                
        cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
        cin>>Qty;
        cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Ibanez Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
        cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
        cin>>again;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    } 

    break;

    default: 
      cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
 }

 }
 while (again == "Yes" || again == "yes");


  cout<<"***********************************Music Shop***********************************"<<endl;
 cout<<"Name of Item                       Quantity             Total Price       "<<endl;
 cout<<"                                                                                "<<endl;
 return 0;

}
}
```

The user can keep buying every time he inputs `yes` and it should print the receipt after saying `no`.

Comment: One important aspect of Computer Science is "Abstraction". Can you try to abstract out the problem from bill/receipts, quantities and price and replace them with objects, variables, classes and explain actually what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: When writing a question try to stick to the problem. You can explain the problem with two menus with two entries. In fact by reworking the question to cut it down to it's essentials you may find you've accidentally discovered the point @kishoredbn has made.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char acoustic, electric, drums, piano, music, equip, Yes, No, y, name;

int pay, Qty;
std::string again;

long long tot=0;
int sumA1=0,sumA2;
int sumB1=0,sumB2;
int QtyA1=0,QtyA2=0,QtyB1=0,QtyB2=0;
string   Accoustic1="Fender Acoustic Guitar",Accoustic2="Hartwood Acoustic Guitar ";
string Electric1="Gibson Electric Guitar",Electric2="Ibanez Electric Guitar";

int main()
{

    {
        cout << "Welcome to the Music Shop" << endl <<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         ===========================                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |       Categories        |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |  [a] Acoustic Guitar    |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |  [b] Electric Guitar    |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |  [c] Drums              |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |  [d] Piano              |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         |  [e] Music Equipments   |                            "<<endl;
        cout << "                                                                         ===========================                            "<<endl;


        do
        {
            cout << "                                                                     Choose from the available categories:";
            cin >> music;
            cout << ""<<endl;

            switch (music)
            {
            case 'a':

                cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |                Acoustic Guitars             |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             | [1] Fender Acoustic Guitar      P6,900.00   |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             | [2] Hartwood Acoustic Guitar    P6,300.00   |" << endl;
                cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
                cin>>acoustic;

                if (acoustic == '1')
                {
                    cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
                    cin>>Qty;
                    cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Fender Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
                    cin>>again;

                    QtyA1+=Qty;
                    sumA1=sumA1+(6900*Qty);

                }
                else if (acoustic == '2')
                {
                    cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
                    cin>>Qty;
                    cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Hartwood Acoustic Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
                    cin>>again;
                    QtyA2+=Qty;
                    sumA2=sumA2+(6300*Qty);
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
                }

                break;

            case 'b':

                cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |                Electric Guitars             |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |                                             |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             |           Product                 Price     |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             | [1] Gibson Electric Guitar      P8,500.00   |" << endl;
                cout<< "                                                             | [2] Ibanez Electric Guitar      P25,000.00  |" << endl;
                cout << "                                                             =============================================== "<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"                                                                Choose from the available Electric Guitars:";
                cin>>electric;

                if (electric=='1')
                {
                    cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
                    cin>>Qty;
                    cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Gibson Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
                    cin>>again;
                    QtyB1+=Qty;
                    sumB1=sumB1+(8500*Qty);
                }
                else if (electric=='2')
                {
                    cout<<"Enter the quantity:";
                    cin>>Qty;
                    cout<<"("<<Qty<<")"<<"Ibanez Electric Guitar was added to your cart"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Would you like to add more item? (Yes/No)"<<endl;
                    cin>>again;

                    QtyB2+=Qty;
                    sumB2=sumB2+(25000*Qty);
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Invalid";
                }

                break;

            default:
                cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
            }

        }
        while (again == "Yes" || again == "yes");


        cout<<"***********************************Music Shop***********************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Name of Item                       Quantity             Total Price       "<<endl;
        cout<<"                                                                                "<<endl;
        if(QtyA1>0)
            cout<<Accoustic1<<" "<<QtyA1<<" "<<sumA1<<endl;
        if(QtyA2>0)
            cout<<Accoustic2<<" "<<QtyA2<<" "<<sumA2<<endl;
        if(QtyB1>0)
            cout<<Electric1<<" "<<QtyB1<<" "<<sumB1<<endl;
        if(QtyB2>0)
            cout<<Electric2<<" "<<QtyB2<<" "<<sumB2<<endl;

        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should be directly posted in your answer, not as a link.

Comment: What did you do? What's the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: This is a code-only answer. To salvage it you should explain what the Asker had done wrong and highlight and explain what you did differently to fix the problem.

Comment: The thing is there's nothing wrong with my code, my question is how. Thanks for the receipt code